# Dynamic Crm 2013 : Quick Output Word Document

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, mailmerge

I need help to find solution to export "Word Document" with templete
that contain primary entity parameters and linked entities parameters.

I use with mail merge , but the method is carried out by a large number of operations to layout.

In CRM 2011 need to click 1 button and the Word Document is ready with all parameters.

someone can help me find solution for this situation

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1. use a third party software like document core pack.

[document core pack](http://www.mscrm-addons.com/Products/AddonsforMSCRM2011/DocumentsCorePackforMSCRM2011/tabid/170/Default.aspx)

1. develop your own plugin to create a document and dump it in a shared drive.
   I have done this before with the use of openxml (you do not have to install office on the server).

[openxml](http://openxmldeveloper.org/)